# can not update THREE.DirectionalLight's direction

Tags: javascript, three.js

The DirectionalLightShadow always lookAt Vector3(0,0,0).

I set its direction below, but it not works. The light.shadow.camera always lookAt (0,0,0)

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
light.position.set(20,0,20)
light.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(400,400,400))
light.castShadow = true
```

here is my code on codepen:

https://codepen.io/iamnotstone/pen/jzrzge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I have to use the light.target to specify the direction.

see the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/lights/DirectionalLight)

> The DirectionalLight points from its position to target.position. The
>   default position of the target is (0, 0, 0). Note: For the target's
>   position to be changed to anything other than the default, it must be
>   added to the scene using